# Are there any restrictions for accommodation in New York?

Tags: usa, international-travel, accommodation, new-york-city

I am looking to go to New York next year and a friend told me that there are restrictions on how long you can stay or where you can stay. Something to do with their laws. I live in Greece by the way.

Is this above true? I want to spend at least 10 days there.

Comment: For international travel, your citizenship matters just as much as your country of residence.  Can you edit your question to include this information?

Comment: I live in Greece as I stated above and my citizenship is Greek. I cannot find how to edit the question. I am new at this.

Comment: To edit your question, use the "edit" link below the text of your question.  And welcome to Travel StackExchange!

Answer (score 19):

I've never heard of limits on how long you can stay in NYC. Perhaps he's confusing this with restrictions on how long people can rent a dwelling [mostly aimed at peer-to-peer rentals like Airbnb](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/04/07/realestate/how-to-host-on-airbnb-legally.html)

> The New York State Multiple Dwelling Law, which covers buildings with three or more units, prohibits transient rentals of fewer than 30 days at a time, unless the owner is present for the time a guest is renting.

These laws are aimed at residents trying to rent their house/apartment. They don't affect you directly.

Comment: In particular, the restriction does not apply to hotel rooms, nor any other accommodation that is intended under the city's laws to be transient.

Comment: What does it mean to have a building with "three or more units"? I mean: an renting a flat with bathroom, bedroom and kitchen is 3 units and thus you must rent at least a month, or does it count as 2 (bathroom not counted)? What if you have 2 rooms: bathroom and bedroom+kitchen combo? I'm interested in this, since I wanted to Airb&b for a week this year...

Comment: @Bakuriu: "unit" is landlord-speak for "apartment"/"flat".

Comment: What a great law.

Comment: @Martha Ah, so if someone owns 3+ flats they are affected by the Dwelling Law, but if they own just 2 and rent one they can do as they please, am I correct?

Comment: @Bakuriu: I have no idea how the law works, but the snippet quoted by Machavity talks about *buildings*, not owners.

Comment: @Bakuriu I would suggest, if you have any questions about the legal interpretation, that you ask over at [Law.SE](//law.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 5):

**TL/DR: 10 Days in New York City is absolutely no problem in any way.**

However, what you friend my be referring to is a collection of residency and rental rules that usually hit around the 30 day mark.

This is the distinction between a short term and long term rental which brings different rules and taxes.

Also, New York has some wonky tax and residency rules.  I recall (fuzzy) a company I worked with would not allow non-New York residents to stay in New York for more than two weeks at a time and would not allow them to commute to New York for more than six months.

Answer (score 4):

No there are no such restrictions, at least not for the city itself. Obviously you need a visa or other permission to enter the US, and there are restrictions on how long you can stay in the US, but not how long you can stay in the city.

Answer (score 1):

Hostels may have a certain limitation on how long you can stay. For example, Hostelling International NYC has a maximum of 20 nights per calendar year (see http://hinewyork.org/about/faq/)